# Is there a SAS PROC statement that allows me to use indicator variables to create a multiple linear regression model?

Tags: variables, sas, linear-regression, categorical-data, indicator

I am trying to find a multiple linear regression model and use numerical data as an indicator variable to tread it as qualitative data. For example, if one of the variables was "cars owned" and the responses were 1, 2, or 3, I would want to use an indicator variable.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer as correct, or provide additional insights to help other users understand how you eventually resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [CLASS statement in PROC GLM](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect011.htm). By placing a variable in CLASS, you instruct SAS to treat it as categorical and convert it into classification variables (that is what you call indicators). To control which level is used as a reference, use `ORDER =` option in PROC GLM statement ([details here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect008.htm)).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with PROC REG?

Comment: @dte324, no, PROC REG does not support CLASS statement.  Instead, you have to recode the variable into a series of dummy variables, e.g., CARS_OWNED_1 with values 1 or 0, CARS_OWNED_2 with values 1 or 0, and so on.

Comment: AlexK is right but do not be afraid of using PROC GLM - it is nothing but a more general version of PROC REG, covering all its model types (and more).